# How to use FrameLayout Properly?

Tags: android, android-layout

I attached my xml code below...How to create one button on top of the LinearLayout.I tried i am not get output.

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_receive_bg"
                android:text="OR"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#F6F6F6"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <SurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>
            </LinearLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

**My output below:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Please give any reference or what i did mistake specify...Thanks in adavace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewGroup` keeps its child elevation from top to bottom `<View>` define in xml i.e the bottom `<View>` in xml will be on top of other views

You need to define your `TextView` in last like this

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">      


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#F6F6F6"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <SurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

            </LinearLayout>

          //Define in bottom to make it on top of other views
           <TextView
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_receive_bg"
                android:text="OR"/>

 </FrameLayout>
```

Or if your minSDK is API 21 than you can use `android:elevation=1dp` attribute to make view on top

Answer (score 1):

Add TextView on TOP

```
   <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#F6F6F6"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <SurfaceView
                    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>
                </LinearLayout>

     <TextView
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_receive_bg"
                    android:text="OR"/>

     </FrameLayout>
```